# Capture multiple arguments with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I am using NSubstitute to write a unit test, and am trying to capture **multiple** method arguments passed in a method call.

I understand that I can capture a single argument using the `Arg.Do<T>()` matcher by doing something like this for `SomeMethod` which only accepts one parameter:

```cs
TArg? receivedArg = null;
SomeClass.SomeMethod(Arg.Do<TArg>(arg => receivedArg = arg));
```

However in my case, `SomeMethod` multiple arguments, and I want to capture all of them in each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Callbacks, void calls and When..Do](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks) topic.

You can hook an `Action<CallInfo>` callback to your `SomeMethod` method; its `CallInfo` argument has an `Args` method that returns all passed arguments as an `object[]` array. There's also an `ArgAt<T>(int position)` method for strong typed access to a specific argument.

---

```
object[] receivedArgs;
int receivedArg1;
string receivedArg2;
bool receivedArg3;

var dependency = Substitute.For<IDependency>();

dependency
    .When(o => o.SomeMethod(Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<bool>()))
    .Do(callInfo =>
    {
        receivedArgs = callInfo.Args();

        receivedArg1 = callInfo.ArgAt<int>(0);
        receivedArg2 = callInfo.ArgAt<string>(1);
        receivedArg3 = callInfo.ArgAt<bool>(2);
    });

var myClass = new MyClass(dependency);
myClass.Run();

// Check received args here.
```

```
public interface IDependency
{
    void SomeMethod(int arg1, string arg2, bool arg3);
}

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public MyClass(IDependency myClass)
    {
        _dependency = myClass;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        _dependency.SomeMethod(123, "foo", false);
    }
}
```